# Create a fake .a file for iOS simiulator

Tags: ios

I've a static library included in my project but that library does not have support for i386 arch. So, is it possible to create a fake .a file which I can use to run it on a simulator. I don't want those methods/feature of the static lib to be executed when I run it in a device. The static library that I use is for Bluetooth communication. is there any direct or a work around to be done.

Comment: I guess you could compile some noop stub yourself based on the header file for that library.

Comment: You should do a selective import depending on your target device.
https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/gcc-4.0.1/cpp/Conditionals.html

Comment: we can create a static library which can support simulator and device both, for all architectures

Comment: if u r looking for some thing like this i can assist you with process.. where u will get one .a file for simulators and one .a file for devices and one .a file for both

Comment: Aditya Sinha : can you brief a bit, since, i've removed those file from the build phase still it proceeds with the same error "Undefined symbols for i386 arch"